# Как добавить бота в Telegram канал с помощью Python

Tags: python, telegram

Я работал с Selenium (Python) и Веб-версией Телеграма, нужно добавить бота в качестве администратора в канал, но так как Веб-версия урезана, нет возможности добавить бота в канал. Через Десктопную версию тоже не нашел решения. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Изучите библиотеку Telethon либо Pyrogram

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему с помощью веб версии telegram "a", также получилось добавить нужного мне бота как администратора канала